# Stream.publish won't translate {*actor*} using Facebook Connect for iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am able to successfully publish a stream to my account using Stream.publish via Facebook Connect for iPhone. However, the `{*actor*}` token does not appear to get translated. I though this was a token that Facebook automatically translates to the user. Is this not the case? Here is my attachment JSON array.

```
attachment = "{"name":"Join {*actor*} PocketBracket Pool - The Pool Name
pool","href":"http://www.pocketbracket.com/pools/1741",
"media":[{"type":"image",
"src":"http://www.pocketbracket.com/library/images/icon_facebook_post.png","href":"http://www.pocketbracket.com"}],"description":"Get
ready for the 2010 Men's College Basketball Tournament! Fill out your own
bracket and challenge your friends with PocketBracket."}";
```

Otherwise, I am only setting message and action_links. Do I need to set `uid`? Again everything shows up correctly, but `{*actor*}` is still literally within my stream.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM, Looks like actor can only go in the caption:

> caption: A subtitle for the post that should describe why the user posted the item or the action the user took. This field can contain plain text only, as well as the {*actor*} token, which gets replaced by a link to the profile of the session user. The caption should fit on one line in a user's stream; make sure you account for the width of any thumbnail.

Please let me know if this is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tag {*actor*} only in caption, tested :)